# How to handle special urls like tel within inappbrowser?

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

Working on a phonegap/cordova project that uses inappbrowser to open a mobile site and use like it was an app. The problem is that tel url links always end up redirecting to a err_unknown_url_scheme on Android.

I do have it whitelisted in config.xml:

Now it opens the dialer properly. The only issue being that it always leads to an error page for Android which doesn't lead to good user experience.

For clarification, the tel link is accessed within a site that is opened up in inappbrowser if that makes a difference.

Anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: which version of cordova re you using ??
you can check the same via cli using this command " cordova --version "

Comment: @404 cordova 5.3.3 is the version

Answer (score 0):

As per the cordova version you mentioned in the comment, you may solve this issue by adding this to the config.xml

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

If that doesn't work try this too

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: I have already tried that unfortunately. That's what I mean by I already have it whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

A recent patch to inappbrowser has solved this issue for me at the time of typing this. I used the following command to re-add/update to the current version of inappbrowser: cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git.